# React Native TabView below a carousel stick to header onScroll - ScrollView

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there any custom component or any native component in React Native using which I can stick a tab view within a scroll view to the header as the onScroll event is fired in the ScrollView?

Any event handlers or logic to implement the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use react-native `ScrollView` to accomplish this using `stickyHeaderIndices`.
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html